# Java code generating a null pointer exception

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception, while-loop, project

I'm getting this Null Pointer Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ATM.isItValid(ATM.java:64)
    at ATM.displayGreeting(ATM.java:59)
    at Bank.runATM(Bank.java:90)
    at Bank.displayBank(Bank.java:109)
    at Bank.addAccount(Bank.java:52)
    at Bank.displayBank(Bank.java:105)
    at Bank.addAccount(Bank.java:52)
    at Bank.displayBank(Bank.java:105)
    at BankDriver.main(BankDriver.java:6)
```

From this code:

```
public void displayGreeting() {
    clearScreen();
    System.out.println("Welcome to Bob's Friendly Bank\n");
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter card number: ");
        currentCard = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter PIN: ");
        currentPIN = input.next();
        System.out.println(currentCard + currentPIN);
    } while (!(isItValid()));
}
public boolean isItValid(){  
   boolean answer = false;
   if(theBank.validCard(currentCard, currentPIN))      //Exception thrown here.
       answer = true;
   return answer;    
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: remove unnecesary code and point out where the error is thrown exactly.

Comment: The previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819712/java-lang-nullpointerexception-with-arraylist

Comment: Use a debugger or old school *pint*-debugging to find the `null` on which you try to call a method.

Comment: Exactly how was the answer to that last question lacking feedback?

Answer (score 3):

ATM.theBank is never being set, thus the null pointer exception is generated as you access it in isItValid

Answer (score 2):

theBank has a null when you invoke its validCard method.  You can't use it before you instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

`theBank` variable in the `ATM` class is not initialized. Are you missing some code perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

`theBank` is null into `ATM`. Here is a way to initialize it:

```
public Bank() {    
    theATM      = new ATM( this);
...


public class ATM {
   ...
   public ATM( Bank bank ) {
      theBank = bank;
      input = new Scanner(System.in);
      currentCard = "";
      currentPIN = "";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`theBank` is not initialized.

If it is a static object, do a `new()` at the class level, otherwise do it in the method.
If it something that needs to be available when you get into the method, pass it as a parameter.

Bonus: always do a `null` check.

```
if(null!=theBank && theBank.validCard(currentCard, currentPIN))
```